# Grouping or pivoting in T-sql I need help either Way

Tags: sql, t-sql

Afternoon all

Ok been trying to build a task summary for staff Here is what I have:

```
SELECT CONCAT (Mpl.FName,' ',Mpl.SName) AS 'Name',
Ctt.TaskName AS 'Task',
Cts.Pickset,
SUM(omo.Qty) 'Total of tasks',
COUNT(Cts.TaskStart) 'Number of Tasks',
CAST(SUM(DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, Cts.TaskStart, Cts.TaskEnd), 0)) AS TIME) AS 'Total Task Time'
FROM CHDS_Management.dbo.People Mpl
LEFT JOIN CHDS_Common.dbo.TaskScan Cts ON Cts.EmpID = Mpl.EmpNo
LEFT JOIN CHDS_Common.dbo.TaskType Ctt ON Ctt.TaskShort = Cts.Task
LEFT JOIN (SELECT picksetno, MAX(PicksetLineNo) AS 'Qty'  FROM CHDS_Common.dbo.OMOrder GROUP BY PicksetNo) omo ON omo.PicksetNo = Cts.Pickset
WHERE Cts.TaskStart >= '2017-06-01 06:00:00'
AND Cts.TaskEnd <= '2017-06-23 02:00:00'
GROUP BY CONCAT (Mpl.FName,' ',Mpl.SName),
ctt.TaskName,
Cts.Pickse
```

What I want to see

```
> Justin Greenwood 
   > Pick 00:01:03
      > 123456 20/06/2017 13:45:45  20/06/2017 13:46:12 00:00:27
      > 123457 20/06/2017 13:47:14  20/06/2017 13:47:24 00:00:10
      > 123458 21/06/2017 15:17:25  21/06/2017 15:17:53 00:00:28
   > Systems 00:00:12
      > Systems 20/06/2017 13:45:05 20/06/2017 13:45:17 00:00:12
```

Even if I cant get the drill down I would like to get something like

```
Justin Pick    100(totel of the 3 tasks) 00:01:03 (time taken for all 3 tasks
Justin Systems 0                         00:00:12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some type of reporting system to get the first result you want--SQL just doesn't work that way. Here's a result like the 2nd. I have no idea what you are summing for the 'Total of the 3 tasks' so you'll need to provide more detail for a more detailed answer.

```
SELECT CONCAT (
        Mpl.FName
        ,' '
        ,Mpl.SName
        ) AS 'Name'
    ,Ctt.TaskName AS 'Task'
    ,Cts.Pickset
    ,SUM(/*whatever you are totaling*/) 'Total of tasks'
    ,COUNT(Cts.TaskStart) 'Number of Tasks'
    ,convert(varchar(8), dateadd(second, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, Cts.TaskStart, Cts.TaskEnd)), 0),  108) AS 'Total Task Time'
FROM CHDS_Management.dbo.People Mpl
LEFT JOIN CHDS_Common.dbo.TaskScan Cts ON Cts.EmpID = Mpl.EmpNo
LEFT JOIN CHDS_Common.dbo.TaskType Ctt ON Ctt.TaskShort = Cts.Task
WHERE Cts.TaskStart >= '2017-06-01 06:00:00'
    AND Cts.TaskEnd <= '2017-06-23 02:00:00'
GROUP BY CONCAT (
        Mpl.FName
        ,' '
        ,Mpl.SName
        )
    ,ctt.TaskName
    ,Cts.Pickset
```

Comment: Thanks but once I remove the sum line as I am working on that bit i still get this error:
1 Operand data type time is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: na still same error also I have added the other lines:

Comment: Thank you bud that works great it took you 2 goes as its Monday morning it taking me all day :)